# Kurdish Sorani Letters sql server

Tags: sql-server, collation, letter

I am trying to create a database containing Kurdish Sorani Letters.
My Database fields has to be varchar cause of project is started that vay.

First I create database with Arabic_CI_AS
I can store all arabic letters on varchar fields but when it comes to kurdish letters for example

ڕۆ  these special letters are show like ?? on the table after entering data, I  think my collation is wrong. Have anybody got and idea for collation ?

Comment: The only collations I can get the value `ڕۆ` to be stored as a `varchar` is with a UTF8 Collation. None of the non-UTF8 Collations can store the value. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=583cc2b5653dd81e2ed9950a53103ea8) (you'll need to ignore the mass of errors for some collations).

Answer (score 3):

With *that* collation, no, you need to use `nvarchar` and always prefix such strings with the `N` prefix:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.floo
(
  UseNPrefix bit,
  a varchar(32) collate Arabic_CI_AS,
  b nvarchar(32) collate Arabic_CI_AS
);

INSERT dbo.floo(UseNPrefix,a,b) VALUES(0,'ڕۆ','ڕۆ');
INSERT dbo.floo(UseNPrefix,a,b) VALUES(1,N'ڕۆ',N'ڕۆ');

SELECT * FROM dbo.floo;
```

Output:

> | UseNPrefix | a | b |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | False | ?? | ?? |
> | True | ?? | ڕۆ |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=670fffd4a9790c441eb86d16ec3bca54)

In SQL Server 2019, you can use a different SC + UTF-8 collation with `varchar`, but you will still need to prefix string literals with `N` to prevent data from being lost:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.floo
(
  UseNPrefix bit,
  a varchar(32) collate Arabic_100_CI_AS_KS_SC_UTF8,
  b nvarchar(32) collate Arabic_100_CI_AS_KS_SC_UTF8
);

INSERT dbo.floo(UseNPrefix,a,b) VALUES(0,'ڕۆ','ڕۆ');
INSERT dbo.floo(UseNPrefix,a,b) VALUES(1,N'ڕۆ',N'ڕۆ');

SELECT * FROM dbo.floo;
```

Output:

> | UseNPrefix | a | b |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | False | ?? | ?? |
> | True | ڕۆ | ڕۆ |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d0f8638bd796c1b6ea63a45e6808d764)

Basically, even if you are on SQL Server 2019, your requirements of "I need to store Sorani" and "I can't change the table" are incompatible. You will need to either change the data type of the column or at least change the collation, and you will need to adjust any code that expects to pass this data to SQL Server without an `N` prefix on strings.

Comment: Dear Aaron thank you for your kindly reply i can change the collation but i cant change column data type. I try  Arabic_100_CI_AS_KS_SC_UTF8 collation.